# Unable to hibernate 18.04, it used to work on windows

Tags: 18.04, hibernate

I recently installed Ubuntu for first time, I have Lenovo G580 Laptop with 8 GB RAM, hibernation used to work pretty will while I was on windows 7.

swap is available with 16 GB size

With Ubuntu 18.04 installed I am unable to hibernate.

**I read various posts that suggests to check if Hibernate works on your system** So I tried following command

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

Also tried:

```
pm-hibernate
```

Both kind of puts my system in hibernation for like 15 seconds and it starts back automatically on login screen.

I cannot cannot shut down and restart my system so frequently as I have to keep a lot of files open. Is there any alternative way to enable it or I have to switch back to windows.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: @Pilot6 I am not able to enter in BIOS. When I press F2 it enters grub

Comment: Choose `System setup` in grub then. You should get into BIOS.

Comment: No System Setup option either.
It only shows grub command line type interface.